# Different realloc behaviour in linux and osx

Tags: c, linux, macos, realloc, errno

I have this simple C program:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    size_t size = 4194304; /* 4 MiB */
    char *buffer = malloc(size);
    char *buffers[10] = {NULL};
    void *tmp_pointer = NULL;
    fprintf(stderr, "initial size == %zu\n", size);
    fprintf(stderr, "initial buffer == %p\n\n", buffer);
    srand(time(NULL));
    /* let's see when it fails ... */
    for (; i < 10; ++i) {
        /* some random writes */
        for (j = 0; j < 1000; ++j) {
            buffer[rand() % size] = (char)(rand());
        }
        /* some interleaving memory allocations */
        buffers[i] = malloc(1048576); /* 1 MiB */
        size *= 2;
        fprintf(stderr, "new size == %zu\n", size);
        tmp_pointer = realloc(buffer, size);
        if ((tmp_pointer == NULL) || (errno != 0)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "tmp_pointer == %p\n", tmp_pointer);
            fprintf(stderr, "errno == %d\n", errno);
            perror("realloc");
            return (1);
        } else {
            buffer = tmp_pointer;
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "new buffer == %p\n\n", buffer);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "Trying to free the buffers.\n");
    free(buffer);
    if (errno != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "errno == %d\n", errno);
        perror("free(buffer)");
        return (2);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        free(buffers[i]);
        if (errno != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "i == %d\n", i);
            fprintf(stderr, "errno == %d\n", errno);
            perror("free(buffers)");
            return (3);
        }
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "Successfully freed.\n");
    return (0);
}
```

It just allocates a 4 MiB of memory and 10 times tries to double its size by reallocation. The simple calls to realloc are interleaved with another allocations of 1 MiB blocks and some random writes in order to minimize the heap allocator "tricks". On the Ubuntu linux machine with 16 GiB RAM, I have the following output:

```
./realloc_test
initial size == 4194304
initial buffer == 0x7f3604c81010

new size == 8388608
new buffer == 0x7f3604480010

new size == 16777216
new buffer == 0x7f360347f010

new size == 33554432
new buffer == 0x7f360147e010

new size == 67108864
new buffer == 0x7f35fd47d010

new size == 134217728
new buffer == 0x7f35f547c010

new size == 268435456
new buffer == 0x7f35e547b010

new size == 536870912
new buffer == 0x7f35c547a010

new size == 1073741824
new buffer == 0x7f3585479010

new size == 2147483648
new buffer == 0x7f3505478010

new size == 4294967296
new buffer == 0x7f3405477010

Trying to free the buffers.
Successfully freed.
```

So, all the reallocations up to the 4 GiB seemingly succeed. However, when I set the kernel virtual  memory  accounting  mode to 2 (always check, never overcommit) by this command:

```
echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

then the output changes to:

```
./realloc_test
initial size == 4194304
initial buffer == 0x7fade1fa7010

new size == 8388608
new buffer == 0x7fade17a6010

new size == 16777216
new buffer == 0x7fade07a5010

new size == 33554432
new buffer == 0x7fadde7a4010

new size == 67108864
new buffer == 0x7fadda7a3010

new size == 134217728
new buffer == 0x7fadd27a2010

new size == 268435456
new buffer == 0x7fadc27a1010

new size == 536870912
new buffer == 0x7fada27a0010

new size == 1073741824
new buffer == 0x7fad6279f010

new size == 2147483648
tmp_pointer == (nil)
errno == 12
realloc: Cannot allocate memory
```

The rellocation fails at 2 GiB. The computer's free memory at the time as reported by `top` has been around 5 GiB, so it is reasonable, because realloc must always allocate continuous block of memory. Now, let's see what happens when running the same program on Mac OS X Lion inside the VirtualBox on the very same machine, but with only 8 GiB of virtual RAM:

```
./realloc_test
initial size == 4194304
initial buffer == 0x101c00000

new size == 8388608
tmp_pointer == 0x102100000
errno == 22
realloc: Invalid argument
```

Here, this program has a problem with the very first realloc to 8 MiB. This is in my opinion very strange, because the virtual computer's free memory at the time as reported by `top` has been around 7 GiB.

The truth is, however, that the realloc in fact succeeded, because its return value is non-NULL (notice the `tmp_pointer` value just before the program termination). But the very same successful call to realloc has also set the errno to nonzero! Now, what is the correct way to handle this situation?

Should I just ignore the errno and check only the return value from the realloc? But then what about some following errno-based error handlers? This is probably not a good idea.

Should I set errno to zero when realloc returns a non-NULL pointer? This appears to be a solution. But ... I have looked here: http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=374. I don't know how authoritative this resource is, but regarding realloc, it is very clear on this:

"... the standard is also explicit that errno cannot be inspected upon success unless documented, ..."

If I understand correctly, it says that: Yeah, when realloc returns NULL you can look at errno, but not otherwise! This said, am I allowed to reset errno to zero? Without ever looking at it? I find it very unclear to understand and decide what's bad and what's good to do.

I still can't understand why is realloc setting this errno in the first place. And what does its value of "Invalid argument" mean? It is not listed in the man pages, they mention only errno ENOMEM (usually number 12). Could something go wrong? Is something in this simple program causing this behaviour under Mac OS X? Probably yes, ... so, the two main questions are:

1. What is wrong?
   and
2. How to correct it? More precisely: How to improve this simple program so that the realloc on Mac OS X leaves the errno at zero when successful?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the purpose of `errno` - it is *only* defined in the case of a failure. To quote the POSIX standard:

> The value of errno should **only be examined when it is indicated to be valid** by a function's return value. **No function** in this volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 **shall set errno to zero**.

(Bold face by me). So you cannot expect `errno` to be 0 after a successful call. You should only check the return value -- then you can determine why it failed using `errno` but not the other way around (i.e., the value of `errno` does *not* indicate the presence of an error condition - that is not its purpose - in fact, it is not touched if there is no error).

Comment: Allright, I understand that the `errno` is only defined in the case of failure. It makes sense.

Comment: It also makes sense to at first check the return value of realloc and only examine the `errno` in case of realloc's failure (NULL return value).

Comment: But I really must disagree with what you said about a successful call to realloc and errno being untouched (not necessarily zero, but unchanged). As I stated in my question, on Mac OS X Lion, this is simply not always true.
The question is, what is causing this strange behaviour and how to avoid it.

Comment: In this case it was probably set to 22 before you called realloc().  But in general, successful calls may and sometimes do set errno.

Comment: @richard-kettlewell I checked the errno before and after the call to realloc and it changed to 22 just **after** the call.

Comment: The code you posted does not check `errno` before the call. Note that the standard only mandates that `errno` cannot be *reset* to zero, but it permits `errno` to be changed to non-zero value even if there is no error so the behavior you described is entirely legal. You should simply not be looking at `errno` after a successful call as its value has absolutely no meaning for that call.

Comment: I know that the code I posted does not check errno before the call. I added the check before the call and just then tested it, of course.

Comment: @SimonUrbanek Thank you for interpreting the standard. I have obviously misunderstood the proper way to check if `realloc` succeeded. Now I suppose it is clear.

Comment: The standard only says that the `errno` shall not be set to zero. This does not stop the function from first setting it to `EINVAL` and then checking it's arguments, with the intention of returning if one of them is invalid, and then continuing with the rest of the function. It doesn't matter as the function has succeeded and therefore the `errno` value is not marked as valid.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there is a bug in the implementation of the realloc().  Reading a bit the source code of eglibc's realloc (https://github.com/Xilinx/eglibc/blob/master/malloc/malloc.c#L2907) it seems the problem happens when the memory cannot be obtained from the main "arena" but from a secondary one, that it is not resetting the errno value to zero.  The errno variable is never set to zero in that file.

Until they fix it, you are probably safe by ignoring an errno==ENOMEM if the return value is not null.